# Comparing the contents of two files, displaying differences

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm looking to compare two files similarly to how you can compare a version of code in source for example to an updated version. I'm still a bit of a slow coder :-S. My problem here is really designing it right, so please step in and tell me how it would work best and hopefully wouldn't be too complex.

So for this my current plan basically is to load in both files into separate text boxes(?). Stream read through both of them separately into two arraylists and compare the arrayslists against each other. And have some additional checks for file size etc.

How could I cycle through the textbox of the one I'm comparing to and highlight for example in red where there are differences? I have no idea how i'd do that?

High level guess, would I read the differences in the two arrays (say element 11) and highlight that data place/element of the textbox?

Comment: get yourself WinDiff and no coding will be required (:.. Aside from that the problem itself is actually quite complex and with tons of options: ignoring whitespace, ignoring capitalization, reordered lines, reordered words...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you're doing this as a learning experience, I suggest leveraging an existing implementation... avoid reinventing the wheel.  Differencing files efficiently is not a trivial undertaking.

There's a C# port of Google's Diff Match Patch

http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/

You can compile that as C# into a DLL and then use the DLL from your VB.Net project.

Even if your objective is to learn, with such a complex topic, I would suggest studying an exiting implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to display the content of the files to be able to compare them. You could use methods from the class `System.IO.File` to read the content and a Linq query to compare them:

Here's a simple and short approach:

```
Dim f1Lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(file1Path)
Dim f2Lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(file1Path)
Dim inFile1Only = f1Lines.Except(f2Lines)
Dim inFile2Only = f2Lines.Except(f1Lines)
Dim sameInBoth = f1Lines.Intersect(f2Lines)
```

You could show the results in different textboxes. You can use

```
TxtSame.Lines = sameInBoth.ToArray()
```

to assign the lines to the `TextBox`.